# Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row -1

Tags: php, function, row, warnings

This is my page code:

```
 <?php
    $dbhost="****";
    $dbname = '****';
    $dbusername="********";
    $dbpass="*****;
    $con = mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpass");
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$con);
    ?>
    <main>
    <table width='100%'  align='center'>
    <tr align='center'>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY data";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $j = $num - 1;
    $fyear = mysql_result($result, $j, "data");
    $year = 2005;
    while ($year <= $fyear)
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE posizione = 'uila/blindi.php' AND YEAR(data) = ".$year." ORDER    BY data";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $i = 0; 
                echo "<td>";
                    while ($i < $num)
                        {
                            $file = mysql_result($result, $i, "pdf");
                            $name = mysql_result($result, $i, "nome");
                            $type = mysql_result($result, $i, "type");
                            $path = mysql_result($result, $i, "posizione");
                            echo "<a href=\"opendoc.php?type={$type}&id={$i}&path={$path}\" TARGET=\"_self\">"?><?php echo $name; ?></a><br>
                            <?php
                            $i++;
                        }
                        echo "</td>";
                        $year++;
                    }
                ?>              
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the page's error:

> Warning: `mysql_result()` [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row -1 on MySQL result index 2 in D:\Inetpub\webs\uilanotiziecom\bindi.php on line 47

The 47th line is : `$j = $num - 1;`

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think the mysql_query is returning an empty set and so the num_rows will be 0. resulting j to be -1.

Comment: Run the query "SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY data" in your mysql command prompt and check what it returns.

Comment: If there is any error, fix the error (like incorrect table/column name or something) otherwise make sure the table has data in it.

Comment: into the table "prodotti" there are 2 rows and it doesn't show them.
Nothing too the code below

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? :

```
 if ( $num >= 1 ) {
      $j = $num - 1;
 }
```

if your query returns 0 rows you get the error, what you do in that case is up to you

Answer (score 0):

I think the below sql query is returning empty result that is where you are facing the issue.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY data";
```

That's why $j value is -1

And FYI,

Please use proper naming conventions and unique variable names as you have used **$sql** for both the queries

Comment: I change    $sql = "SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY data";
in    $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY data";

But nothing change

Comment: Roberto are you getting any records for your $sql query ?

Comment: no but i need it for to arrange single file in diffent column (for years)

Comment: are there other advice? i really need to solve this error quickly